# Let $(a_n)_n$ be a convergent sequence of integers , what can we say about $(a_n)_n$

Tags: analysis

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a convergent sequence of integers , what can we say about $(a_n)_n$?

(I don't understand what is meant by this question)

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: @Mohan: The OP is asking for help understanding what the question is asking.

Comment: @Fayz: have you found an example of a convergent sequence of integers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that the sequence converges to some number $L$. Then for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge m_\epsilon$. In particular, there is an $m_{1/4}\in\Bbb N$ such that $$|a_n-L|<\frac14$$ whenever $n\ge m_{1/4}$. Using the triangle inequality, we see that if $k,n\ge m_{1/4}$, then

$$|a_k-a_n|\le|a_k-L|+|L-a_n|<\frac14+\frac14=\frac12\;.$$

Now remember: each of these terms $a_n$ is an **integer**. What can you say about integers that are less than $\frac12$ apart?

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk: I needed to ensure that $|a_n-L|<\frac12$ in order to ensure that $|a_k-a_n|<1$. Thus, I could have used any positive $\epsilon\le\frac12$. I just chose $\frac14$ because the resulting numbers are simple and make it obvious why $a_k$ must be equal to $a_n$.

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk: I told you why I needed to make $|a_n-L|<\frac12$: to ensure that $|a_k-a_n|<1$. If you know that $a_k$ and $a_n$ are integers and that $|a_k-a_n|<1$, what can you conclude about $a_k$ and $a_n$? It’s something that you could **not** conclude if $|a_k-a_n|$ were $1$ or more.

Comment: @GoNK: That’s right: it turns out the such a sequence must be constant from some point on.

Comment: @GoNK: You’re welcome. Yes: in the notation in my answer we have $a_n=a_{m_{1/4}}$ for all $n\ge m_{1/4}$.