# Suppose that a sequence of rational fractions p/q converge to an irrational number

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, irrational-numbers

Suppose that a sequence of (rational) fractions p/q converge to an irrational number r. Show that q converges to infinity.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. 
In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts 
and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, 
and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems to me that irrationality of the number $r$ is not really the key issue. Indeed, if we exclude sequences that have eventually constant tails (not much of a restriction), then this property holds for **EVERY** real number $r.$

Answer (score 2):

What a cute question!

Let $r_n = p_n/q_n$.  $r_n \rightarrow x$. $x \not \in \mathbb Q$.

Suppose $q_n \rightarrow y$.  Then for $1/2>\epsilon>0$ there exists and $N$ such that $|q_n - q_m| \le |q_n - y| + |y-q_m| <\epsilon + \epsilon <1$ for all $m,n > N$.  But $q_n,q_m$ are integers so $|q_n - q_m| < 1 \iff q_n = q_m$.  So there exists an $N$ where all $q_{n; n>N}$ are an equal constant integer, $y$.

If $r_n \rightarrow x$ then $\{r_n*y\} \rightarrow xy$.  For $n > N$, $r_n*y = p_n*y/q_n = p_n*y/y = p_n \in \mathbb Z$.  So, by the exact same argument as above: {$r_n*y$} becomes a sequence of integers for $n > N$.  As this converges there is an $M$ where $r_n*y$ is an equal constant integer, $p$, for all n > M.

So for $n > M$, $r_n*y = p \implies r_n = p/y$ and $r_n \rightarrow p/y = x \in \mathbb Q$.

This A contradiction.

So $q_n$ doesn't converge.

Comment: I like this solution too! It very much makes clear why a subsequence of $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ converges to an integer. +1

Comment: For further reference: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311955/let-a-n-n-be-a-convergent-sequence-of-integers-what-can-we-say-about-a-n

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{(\frac{p}{q})_k\}$ be a sequence of of rational numbers such that $ \{(\frac{p}{q})_k\}=\frac{\{p_n\}}{\{q_n\}}$ and so that the sequence converges to $r \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$.

Suppose that $\lim_{n \to \infty}q_n=Q$.

If $p_n$ converges, we have a contradiction to the irrationality or $r$, since this would imply that it converges to some $z \in \mathbb{Z}$.

If $p_n$ diverges, $\frac{p_n}{Q}$ also diverges to infinity, contradicting the fact that the sequence is convergent.

Comment: Sorry for the bad notation, I hope the idea is clear.